# Shell multiple choices list fails

Tags: linux, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

ARG_ARRAY=(num1 num2 num3 num4 num5 num6 num7 num8 num9 num10)
dir=$(find . -type f)
i=0

for f in ${dir[@]};do
        printf "$((++i)) $f      "
done

printf "\nPlease select the files:\n"
echo "Using the numbers like: 1 2 4 5 "

read ${ARG_ARRAY[@]}


echo $num1
echo $num2
echo $num3
echo $num4
echo $num5
echo $num6
echo $num7
echo $num8
echo $num9
echo $num10

for f in ${ARG_ARRAY[@]}
do
        var=$f
        echo ${$var}
done
```

code above intends to show all the files in . and let the usr choose them, then print the file names user selected. But I find this sequence can successfully print

```
echo $num1
echo $num2
echo $num3
echo $num4
echo $num5
echo $num6
echo $num7
echo $num8
echo $num9
echo $num10
```

while this get error

```
for f in ${ARG_ARRAY[@]}
do
        var=$f
        echo ${$var}
done


./test.sh: line 30: num1: command not found

./test.sh: line 30: num2: command not found

./test.sh: line 30: num3: command not found

./test.sh: line 30: num4: command not found

./test.sh: line 30: num5: command not found

./test.sh: line 30: num6: command not found

./test.sh: line 30: num7: command not found

./test.sh: line 30: num8: command not found

./test.sh: line 30: num9: command not found

./test.sh: line 30: num10: command not found
```

Can anybody help me to fix this problem ? why the second way fails ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `eval` for that purpose, e.g.:

```
for f in ${ARG_ARRAY[@]}
do
    var=$f
    eval echo \$$var
done
```